# How to use a decorators on class members?

Tags: python, class, flask, python-decorators

I'm trying to write a flask server class, but I'm getting an error on the decorator method.

```
class Server:
    def __init__(self, port):
        self.server = flask.Flask(__name__)
        self.port = port


    @self.server.route("/isRunning/<int:index>/")
    def isRunning(self, index):
        while (not self.running):
            time.sleep(0.5)

        return "Ok"


    def run(self):
        self.server.run(host="localhost", port=self.port)


a = Server(5000)
a.run()
```

```
  File "Server.py", line 20, in Server 
     @self.server.route("/login/<string:name>/<int:r>/<int:g>/<int:b>/")
NameError: name 'self' is not defined
```

I'm guessing by this that decorators can't access this instance. What's the correct way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `route` as a decorator, but as a simple function to be called.

```
class Server:
    def __init__(self, port):
        self.server = flask.Flask(__name__)
        self.port = port
        self.server.route("/isRunning/<int:index>/")(self.isRunning)

    def isRunning(self, index):
        while (not self.running):
            time.sleep(0.5)
        return "OK"

    def run(self):
        self.server.run(host="localhost", port=self.port)

a = Server(5000)
a.run()
```

(Note, too, that in `Server.run`, the reference to `app` should be a reference to `self.server`.)